# Should Symfony be directing its users to Stack Overflow for support?

Tags: discussion, product-support

The [Symfony support page](https://symfony.com/support) directs its users primarily to Stack Overflow, and then to its own Slack channel, and finally its own help desk (for paid products only).

> ## Symfony Support
>
> ### Community Support
>
> #### Use Stack Overflow
>
> to ask/answer Symfony questions.
>
> #### Use the Slack chat
>
> to get real-time support or advice.
>
> If you prefer, you can still use our IRC chat.
>
> ### Symfony Products Support (excluding Open-Source products)
>
> If you need support for Symfony products, please contact us using the following form.

The [Stack Overflow product support page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) says:

> Stack Overflow can help support your product but **it can't be the only support**. There are issues that only you can address, and if you send your users to Stack Overflow for them they'll just get frustrated. **Guide your users in where to ask what**

(emphasis mine)

So, they do provide other means of support, but suggest Stack Overflow first, and they don't "guide their users in where to ask what".

Is Sensio Labs using Stack Overflow the way it's intended?

Comment: The link to Stack Overflow at least goes to [questions tagged with 'symfony'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony), not directly the "Ask Question" page nor SO homepage.

Comment: I guess the users have to guide themselves (by reading help center).